# Entering Parameters in Python

Tags: python, excel, random, parameters

I am trying to input parameters into `random.triangular()`, which would be `(low,high,mode)`.

To get the parameters I am extracting them from an Excel cell. Basically I had to create an array so that, for example `parameters[0] = 1,3,2`, where `1,3,2` is what I need to input into the triangular function.

I am fairly new to Python/Excel integration and also to the `random` functions, so what I'm asking is is it even possible for me to get those parameters from the array and use them in the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's no problem at all (if I understand you correctly).

You can simply call

```
random.triangular(*parameters[0])
```

The asterisk in this scenario is called the "[unpacking operator](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)", and it will take an iterable and unpack its items so they can be fed as parameters into the function.

```
>>> import random
>>> parameters = [[1,3,2], [4,5,6]]
>>> random.triangular(*parameters[0])
1.796949832039262
```

If the parameters are in fact stored as strings, you should rethink your data model. You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to parse a literal string:

```
>>> import ast
>>> dumb_parameters = ["1,3,2", "4,5,6"]
>>> parameters = [ast.literal_eval(s) for s in dumb_parameters]
>>> parameters
[(1, 3, 2), (4, 5, 6)]
>>> random.triangular(*parameters[0])
2.2933615845752904
```

Comment: Using a pointer works for using the cell data but now the numbers are being read as a string so it reads (1,2,3) as 5 arguments instead of 3. Is there a way to separate each number so that I can use higher numbers as well?

Comment: Uh, so `1,2,3` is a string, not a list, then? Otherwise, you wouldn't get five elements. What do you get when you do `print(repr(parameters[0]))`?

Comment: By the way, there is no pointer in this code. Python doesn't have pointers. Don't confuse Python syntax with C syntax...

Comment: I guess my main problem is that when I scan the excel column i get a list: [ , , , , ,'1, 2, 3', , ] and I am having a lot of difficulty turning that string into 3 separate integers to use.

Comment: Also when I do that I get "u'1, 2, 3'"

Comment: @AJK: OK, that's a Unicode string. Doesn't matter, `ast.literal_eval()` should handle those just fine.